# How to use Logstash split with field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have the following data stored in the file `data.json`:

```
{"result":[{"number":"1"},{"number":"2"}]}
```

This is my logstash conf file:

```
input {
   file {
       path => "C:/work/apps/ELK/data.json"
       start_position => "beginning"
       sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
   }
}

filter {
   split {     
       field => "result"
   }
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       index => "so"
       document_type => 1
   }
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

When I run Logstash with this configuration and the data above it I get only one entry in Elastic with the whole text (see image below).

[image: Result in Kibana without carriage return]

When I modify the data to add new lines for example:

```
"result":[
{"number":"1"},
{"number":"2"}]
```

`result` is still ignored but this time I do have a split, according to the new lines. I get three messages in database:
[image: Result in Kibana]

I tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558535/logstash-how-do-i-split-an-array-using-the-split-filter-without-a-target) with the original json file but again nothing is parsed (like in the first case). I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The split filter doesn't work since the field result does not exist. To create it, you need to parse the json you're reading from the file, which will create the fields.

To parse the json, use either the [json codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json.html) on your input or the [json filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html).

FYI, the final configuration used:

```
input {
   file {
      path => "C:/work/apps/ELK/data.json"
      start_position => "beginning"
      sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
   }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
        remove_field => ["message", "host", "path"]
    }
    split {
        field => "result"
        add_field => {
            "number" => "%{[result][number]}"           
        }
        remove_field => "result"
   }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "so"
        document_type => 1
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Indeed it works with the two solutions. Personnally, I chose the json filter solution and then made the split. I put the code used in your answer.